# Override properties of php for HHVM

Tags: travis-ci, hhvm

i try use `phpenv config_add ./new.php.ini` in job for HHVM, but job is filed with message

> cp: cannot create regular file `/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/hhvm/etc/conf.d': No such file or directory

How can I override some properties on travis-ci?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `/etc/hhvm/php.ini`, and put your settings in there.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to run `pnpenv config_add` in **hhvm** environment:

```
before_script:
  - |
    if [[ $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION = "hhv"* ]]; then
      cat new.php.ini >> /etc/hhvm/php.ini
    else
      phpenv config-add new.php.ini
    fi
```

Comment: Just the solution I needed, Thanks.